# How to get the directory of a sourced script in RedHat 6 with bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get the path of the script that I'm sourcing. I'm doing the following:

```
DIR="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
```

Nevertheless I get

```
readlink: invalid option -- 'b'
```

I'm on a RedHat 6 machine using bash. Not sure if I'm suppose to do this in a different way.

Comment: If you are sourcing the script then `$0` will be the name of the shell, e.g. `/bin/bash`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/determining-path-to-sourced-shell-script?rq=1

Comment: ...and if your shell is a login shell, the name willl be something like `-bash`, hence the readlink command will ultimately be `readlink -f -bash`, and that explains the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}`:

```
script_dir=$( dirname "$( readlink -f "${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}" )" )
```

This is an array that contains the source files for the current shell function call stack, and the last element of it will be the source of the main script.

This ought to work regardless of whether the script was sourced with `source` or not.

The particular version of `bash` that you are using is version 4.2.1.  Negative indexes in arrays (that references from the end of the array) were added in version 4.3.  To get the same effect as using `${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}` in a pre-4.3 version of `bash`, use

```
${BASH_SOURCE[ ${#BASH_SOURCE[@]} - 1 ]}
```

Comment: it works for me but without the `{}`, like this `$BASH_SOURCE[-1]`

Comment: @WooWapDaBug Are you saying it _doesn't_ work with `${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}`?  Using `$BASH_SOURCE[-1]` would give you a file path (potentially the wrong one) with a trailing `[-1]` at the end.

Comment: you are right. I don't know what was causing the problem then.

Comment: but `${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}` doesn't work. `$BASH_SOURCE` does work... `${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}`  seems empty

Comment: @WooWapDaBug What is your version of `bash`?

Comment: I'm just testing, and this doesn't work `export test=(1 2 3) && echo ${test[-1]}`. It reports `-bash: test: bad array subscript`. My bash version is `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)`

Comment: @WooWapDaBug You can't export an array variable. I'll be back in a moment, I'm traveling...

Comment: @WooWapDaBug Right. Some digging after release notes etc. resulted in an update to my answer.

Comment: Great! Thank you, works like a charm. Do you know if these old method would still work in the newer versions?

Comment: @WooWapDaBug It seems to work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand you, this should work:

```
whereami=$(pwd)
echo $whereami
```

Comment: The problem is that I could be executing the script from a different folder

Comment: Hmm. Yes you are right. This code work if you in the same path wih script.