# Concatenate pwd and basename

Tags: linux, bash, pwd, basename

I want to assign the path and file name to a variable:

```
/path/to/myfile/file.txt
```

For example

```
MYFILE=$(pwd)$(basename)
```

How can i do it ?

Comment: If the purpose is to extract the name of the script itself (as in your own answer), then this is almost a duplicate of the question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4650/determining-path-to-sourced-shell-script

Comment: assigning an arbitrary file name and path is a slightly different question than getting your own script name; which is it?

Comment: well in first i just wanted how to contact output of two linux command , which will provide me full path + myfilename variable. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question as it is stated: This is a simple string concatenation.

```
somedirpath='/some/path'  # for example $PWD or $(pwd)
somefilepath='/the/path/to/file.txt'

newfilepath="$somedirpath"/"$( basename "$somefilepath" )"
```

You most likely would want to include a `/` between the two path elements when concatenating the strings, and `basename` takes an argument which is a path (this was missing in the question).

---

Reading your other answer, it looks like you are looking for the `bash` script path and name.  This is available in `BASH_SOURCE`, which is an array.  It's only element (unless you are in a function) will be what you want.  In the general case, it's the *last* element in the array that you want to look at.

In `bash` 4.4, this is `${BASH_SOURCE[-1]}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its clear now ! i have the following code :
PATH="/mnt/c/Users/omar_bistami/Documents/testvad/afficher.sh"
echo $PATH
echo $(basename "$PATH")
And i get line 6: basename: command not found
I tried `basename "$PATH"`and $( basename "$PATH" )
But still getting the error , tried in 2 differents env.

Comment: @OmarBISTAMI That is because `PATH` is a _very special variable_ used by the shell to look up external utilities. Please use almost any other variable name. Normally, one's own scripts should use lower-case variable names so that they don't accidentally clash with system environment variables.

Comment: yes... was overridden the path..big thanks!

Comment: @OmarBISTAMI See addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked :

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT=$(pwd)$(basename $0)
echo $SCRIPT
```

If there is a better way, please share.

Comment: It looks like you want to have the name of the script? Is that right?

Comment: i wanted the full path+scriptname : /file/to/path/script.sh :)